# How to delay onTouch after one motion event?

Tags: java, android, touch

I am working on an application that involves using a touch to add to a value. In order to stop the value from rising too quickly, I created a boolean that is checked to be true before the method is called and set it to false after it is called. I did this so it would be impossible to double touch and add twice what should be added to the value. But, what I noticed was that if you touched the screen quickly enough, you could call the method before the boolean is set within the first call. But I know the basic functionality works because if I wait just a little bit longer before touching a second time the boolean is correctly set and the method is not called.

I am wondering if there is a way to stop android from detecting touch events for a period of time or something to delay until the boolean is set.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use a ReentrantLock to synchronize your app logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

example code:

```
BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            queue.offer(1); // add queue if empty
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}

public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                queue.take(); // wait for item in queue
                // this code is executed after putting item into queue

                // TODO

                Thread.sleep(100); // wait before next execution
        }
    }
```